# how to get current page source from asp.net aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Hi, I am trying to get the current page source by using the asp.net application. I found a piece of code which converts html to pdf but in order to convert my page to pdf I need to get the html code of the page. How can I get these as a string? My simple code is like this:

```
        string sPathToWritePdfTo = Server.MapPath("") + "/pdf_dosya_adi.pdf";

        System.Text.StringBuilder sbHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sbHtml.Append("<html>");
        sbHtml.Append("<body>");
        sbHtml.Append("<font size='14'>HTML den PDF çevirme Test</font>");
        sbHtml.Append("<br />");
        sbHtml.Append("Body kısmında yazacak yazı");
        sbHtml.Append("</body>");
        sbHtml.Append("</html>");

        using (System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.FileStream

        (sPathToWritePdfTo, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            Pdfizer.HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdf = new Pdfizer.HtmlToPdfConverter();
            htmlToPdf.Open(stream);
            htmlToPdf.Run(sbHtml.ToString());
            htmlToPdf.Close();
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "friendlypdfname.pdf"));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(sPathToWritePdfTo);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

If I can get the html code off my asp.net page I put all line of my page into the 
 sbHtml.Append("");
code by using a for loop and this will solve my problem in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is to use a WebClient to send an HTTP request to the given page and get the resulting HTML:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string html = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/somepage.aspx");
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that it sends an additional HTTP request.

Another possibility is to render the WebForm directly into a string:

```
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    Server.Execute("SomePage.aspx", writer);
    string html = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

Comment: @EmreAltun, if you want to use the WebClient you need to specify the full address to the webpage.

Comment: I use this code but it always calling my current page again and it cause the loop.

Comment: @EmreAltun, you should put the code that generates the PDF in some click handler or something. Not in the Page_Load. It's obvious that if you put it in the Page_Load it would cause an infinite loop. You must have a HTML version of the page first.

Comment: +1 for the ideas, but what if he try to get the source of the same page ? with this 2 ideas he crash the page, because he going to run again and again the same page. I think that he must include a flag on the url to not re-generate again if the question come from inside the page.

Comment: yes what I want to do is getting the source of the same page so I can not get rid of the infinite loop are there any solution for this matter ?

Comment: @EmreAltun, as Aristos suggested you could use a query string parameter to either render the HTML or the PDF from the Page_Load.

Comment: I doubt if the second solution includes values that were modified from codebehind in page_load.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hidden field, add the current html to it, and on an asyc postback be able to retrieve it from within an event. Assuming you are rendering a page, maybe making edits or altering data, and then clicking a button to download for pdf.

//Hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdn_container" />
```

//Button with client side event and serverside event. Should be wrapped in an UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" OnClientClick="refreshHtml();" OnClick="btnDownloadButton_Click" Text="Download Pdf"></asp:Button>
```

//Script tag at bottom of page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function refreshHtml() {
           document.getElementById('<%= hdn_container.ClientID %>').value = document.head.innerHTML + document.body.innerHTML;
        }
</script>
```

//Then in c# you can get the pages html from the hidden field.

```
hdn_container.Value
```

Make sure to set an appropriate AsyncPostBackTimeout for your script manager. And in your webconfig, an appropriate maxRequestLength and executionTimeout.