# Render asp.NET page asynchronously in background and store the result page on a file or memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf

I have a lot of reports that I built in .ASPX pages. These reports are very slow and are causing delay to user visualization.

Now I want to generate the reports in a file or memory, but the pages had a lot of repeater components and rules. So, I really need to load the pages. But without showing to the user. It needs to run in background.

I thought about re-draw the reports in a PDF file, but are too much reports with a lot of stuff inside. So a thought to just load pages in memory a than just convert  to PDF, avoiding a lot of work and possible troubles with existing rules on the aspx pages.

Its possible to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how you could cache the pages for future requests? Or are you asking on how you could make the pages feel more responsive?

Comment: I Need to run this on background and than save the HTML built in a file. Than I gonna convert this to PDF. All of these to avoid recreate every report.

Comment: This answer shows you some possible solutions to get the HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9668127/612036. From there if you want to make it a PDF you'd want to search for a 3rd party library that can convert HTML to PDF